# Using the int type in the printf function does not add the same value as the float type

Tags: c

When I use the following code, the output result is 0 when adding the sum in the `printf` function, but when I add the `printf` function it should be `printf("test: %d", c/ 2);`The output is 1，
Why?

```
int main() {
    float a = 1.5;
    int b = 2;
    int c = a + b;
    printf("test: %d", (a+b)/ 2);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate here: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). Basically if one operand is float and the other int, the int will get promoted to float.

Answer (score 5):

Since you assign the result of `a + b` to an `int` variable, its result will be *truncated*.

So while the result of `1.5 + 2` is `3.5`, the result assigned to `c` will be the integer `3`.

And since both `c` and `2` are `int` values the result of `c / 2` will be an `int` which will be truncated. So the result of `3 / 2` will simply be `1`.

---

With the edit and the new print:

```
printf("test: %d", (a+b)/ 2);
```

Because one of the values involved in the expression `a + b` is a `float`, the result will be a `float`. And because of that the result of the division will *also* be a `float`.

The result of `(a + b) / 2` will be a `float`. But since it's passed as an argument to a variable-argument function like `printf` it will be *promoted* to a `double`. So your statement is essentially equivalent to:

```
printf("test: %d", (double)((a+b)/ 2));
```

Now for the big problem: The `%d` format specifier expects an **`int`** value. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to ***undefined behavior***.

Comment: I found a bug in my question code, I fixed it, I wonder why using (a+b)/2 outputs 0 instead?

Comment: Thank you very much, a word to wake up the dreamer